# Bash: Couldn't resolve the unexpected token syntax error

Tags: bash, vagrant-provision, vvv-wordpress

**Aim:** I'm trying to set up [VVV](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV) where I'm intending not to run DB backups by default, on specific databases.

**Where I'm stuck:** I keep getting the `` syntax error near unexpected token `done' `` even when I use line breaks in bash script.

**Steps taken:** I also ensured that I've the LF line endings in both bash scripts, yet I get the same error.

File: **vagrant_halt_custom**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# This script is run whenever `vagrant halt` is used to power off
# the virtual machine. To customize this behavior, include a file
# in your local VVV/config/homebin directory: vagrant_halt_custom
#
# Look for a custom trigger file. If this exists, we'll assume that
# all trigger actions should be handled by this custom script. If
# it does not exist, then we'll handle some basic tasks.
db_backup_custom
```

File: **db_backup_custom**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Create individual SQL files for each database. These files
# are imported automatically during an initial provision if
# the databases exist per the import-sql.sh process.
mysql -e 'show databases' | \
grep -v -F "information_schema" | \
grep -v -F "performance_schema" | \
grep -v -F "mysql" | \
grep -v -F "test" | \
grep -v -F "Database" | \
while read dbname; do if [ "$dbname" == "mydb" ]; then echo "Database $dbname skipped." && continue fi; mysqldump -uroot "$dbname" > /srv/database/backups/"$dbnme".sql && echo "Database $dbname backed up..."; done
```

**Error**

```
==> default: Running triggers before halt...
/home/vagrant/bin/db_backup_custom: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
/home/vagrant/bin/db_backup_custom: line 12: `while read dbname; do if [ "$dbname" == "mydb" ]; then echo "Database $dbname skipped." && continue fi; mysqldump -uroot "$dbname" > /srv/database/backups/"$dbnme".sql && echo "Database $dbname backed up..."; done'
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: [vagrant-hostsupdater] Removing hosts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the following answer after numerous trial and error.

File: **db_backup_custom**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Create individual SQL files for each database. These files
# are imported automatically during an initial provision if
# the databases exist per the import-sql.sh process.
mysql -e 'show databases' | \
grep -v -F "information_schema" | \
grep -v -F "performance_schema" | \
grep -v -F "mysql" | \
grep -v -F "test" | \
grep -v -F "Database" | \
while read dbname; do
    if [ "$dbname" == "mydb" ] ; then
        echo "Database $dbname skipped." \
            && continue;
    fi
    mysqldump -uroot "$dbname" > /srv/database/backups/"$dbnme".sql &&
        echo "Database $dbname backed up..."; done;
```

**Tip:** Use the following command to verify if your bash script has any syntax errors.

```
bash -n bin/db_backup_custom
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a missing semicolon after `continue`.

Any reason you don't format the code to more lines?

```
while read dbname; do
    if [ "$dbname" == "mydb" ] ; then
        echo "Database $dbname skipped."
            && continue
    fi
    mysqldump -uroot "$dbname" > /srv/database/backups/"$dbnme".sql &&
        echo "Database $dbname backed up..."
done
```

BTW, the backslashes after `|` aren't needed as the command can't end with a lone pipe.

Comment: I tried a slightly modified version of your answer and it helped. I couldn't post it in comments, hence posting as a separate answer. But thank you very much, you saved my day!

Comment: "Any reason you don't format the code to more lines?" - The code belongs to VVV repo and it was formatted that way. So I tried sticking to their standards.